# Can someone help me? I do not know how to continue with the problem.

Tags: geometry, triangles, ratio

Parallelogram ABCD is given. The angle bisector of $\angle DAB$ intersects the side $\overline{DC}$ in the point L and the diagonal in the point K. Let $\overline{DK}:\overline{KB}=3:4$.
Calculate the length of $\overline{LC}$ if the perimeter od the parallelogram is 28.

From the perimeter  i found the sum $a+b=14$ (a,b are the sides of parallelogram where 'a' is the longer side). I marked $\overline{DK}:\overline{KB}$ like $\overline{DK}:\overline{KB}=3k:4k$ so the diagonal DB is: $\overline{DB}=3k+4k=7k$. What should i do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $AB=a$ and $CL=x$.

Thus, $LD=a-x$, $AD=14-a$ and since $\Delta ABK\sim\Delta LDK$, we obtain:
$$\frac{a}{a-x}=\frac{4}{3}.$$ 
Also, we have $$\frac{a}{14-a}=\frac{4}{3},$$ which gives $a=8$ and $x=2$.

Comment: How to know that ΔABK∼ΔLDK?

Comment: @Mathlearner Because $AB||LD$ and from here $\measuredangle BAK=\measuredangle DLK$ and $\measuredangle KBA=\measuredangle KDL$

Comment: Thank you,  i understand it.

Comment: @Mathlearner You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

- Due to [Angle bisector theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem) we have that $|DA| : |AB| = 3 : 4$.
- Because $AB$ and $DC$ are parallel, $|\angle DLA| = |\angle LAB| = |\angle DAL|$.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to get the solution by that.